# Any way to force a specific plugin to use single site tables in multisite installation?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I'm developing a multisite network, and my client wants to have a front-end user dashboard on a separate site (site B), which would pull data from & enable user to use specific functionality from another website in the network (site A).

I was able to accomplish some of this by creating custom shortcodes that switched to site A (switch_to_blog('')), execute plugin shortcode, and return it to site B, but this doesn't always work (for example, Ultimate Member user activity plugin stores typed in activity entry in site B tables anyway).

Is there a way to force a specific plugin to use a single site tables instead? It seems like this would be a much more elegant solution, but I was unable to find any information on it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-upgrade-capability/ its provides a way to link to or more sites together.  One site acts at the main user base and the other sites link back allowing users to enter other sub-sites for different functions.  Its effectively a way to join another site to an existing one and the users don't need to know they are on a second site.  It may take you towards what you are attempting.